# Meaningful values of Inclusive Duration in C++ Build Insights?

Tags: c++, profiling, windows-performance-analyzer

I have used vcperf to analyze the build process of a C++ project in order to see if there're bottlenecks, but the representation of the values is not very insightful.

For instance, the whole Duration is said to be `3,289.218` seconds, which accounts to roughly 54 minutes - the total time it took to build the project (using 14 threads).
But if I look into, for example the files report, I have `<chrono>` Included Path as a number one with the longest `Inclusive Duration (s) Sum` as `3,577.424` which doesn't make sense to me. I might assume that it is the sum across all the threads, but I don't find it useful for analysis.
In order to see the impact I need to understand the actual percentage of the total build time, meaning that either `Duration` has to be calculated in the same manner (spent in all the threads?) or the Inclusive Duration to be calculated as a part of Duration.

Is there a way to get the meaningful values in Windows Performance Analyzer or do I have to use the Build Insights SDK and do some custom calculations?

---

I've looked into the [TopHeaders](https://github.com/microsoft/cpp-build-insights-samples) example that uses the SDK and they have the following code:

```
    AnalysisControl OnStopActivity(const EventStack& eventStack) override
    {
        switch (eventStack.Back().EventId())
        {
        case EVENT_ID_FRONT_END_FILE:
            MatchEventStackInMemberFunction(eventStack, this, 
                &TopHeaders::OnStopFile);
            break;

        case EVENT_ID_FRONT_END_PASS:
            // Keep track of the overall front-end aggregated duration.
            // We use this value when determining how significant is
            // a header's total parsing time when compared to the total
            // front-end time.
            frontEndAggregatedDuration_ += eventStack.Back().Duration();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return AnalysisControl::CONTINUE;
    }
```

This seems *almost* useful, since their program shows the actual percentage of time it takes to parse the header: 7% for `chrono`.
7% of a total duration of 50 minutes is somewhat significant. But it is a percentage of the **front end** pass. What percentage is front end pass itself? 30? 50? Can't say. Hence, can't know the actual impact...

Now, I think this code can be modified by adding other [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build-insights/reference/sdk/c-event-data-types/event-id-enum) ids.